# rspec + capybara: feature testing only 1 expectation per test?

Tags: rspec, tdd, capybara, integration-testing

I'm writing some feature tests for my Rails 4 app using rspec and capybara.  I have it working properly, but I'm struggling to make sense of some aspects of testing this way.

I've been reading that each test (it "should ..." block) should test only 1 thing.  Ok, that sounds great, but when I put that into practice I end up writing a ton of tests for simple things.

Let's say I have a standard signup form that takes email, password, and credit card.

So test write a feature test for my signup, do I have to write 3 separate tests to test the feature?

```
describe "Signup" do
  it "informs user of an invalid email" do
    visit signups_path
    fill_in "Email", with: ""
    click_button "Signup"
    expect(page).to have_text("Email can't be blank")
  end
  it "informs user of an invalid password" do
    visit signups_path
    fill_in "Email", with: "test@test.com"
    fill_in "Password", with: ""
    click_button "Signup"
    expect(page).to have_text("Password can't be blank")
  end
  it "informs user of an invalid credit card" do
    visit signups_path
    fill_in "Email", with: "test@test.com"
    fill_in "Password", with: "valid-password"
    fill_in "Card", with: "bogus"
    click_button "Signup"
    expect(page).to have_text("Card is invalid")
  end
end
```

It would seem simpler to test all of these in a single test.  I'm struggling to find writing on the proper method of performing feature testing.  I don't want to start randomly writing tests that (1) don't actually cover/test my code or (2) become bloated and slow because I was writing them incompetently.  I understand the necessity of tests, just not sure how to best approach feature tests like the one above.

Comment: Why do you feel that it would be simpler to write a single test?

Comment: @JustinKo, I thought it would be simpler because for each test I'm in the same "scenario" with each test having a lot of duplicate code. After looking into it for a while, though, I've concluded that cleaning up duplicate code in `before` blocks helps a lot and true tests should only have 1 `expect/assert` in them to really help pin-point problems. By "simpler" I guess I meant "shorter". But sometimes shorter isn't always better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should DRY up your code to minimize duplication. You can move directives you call at the beginning of each test to `before`, and extract helper method for the repeated code:

```
describe "Signup" do
  before do
    visit signups_path
  end

  def fill_form(fields = {})
    fields.each do |field_name, field_value|
      fill_in field_name.to_s.capitalize, with: field_value
    end
    click_button "Signup"
  end

  it "informs user of an invalid email" do
    fill_form email: ""

    expect(page).to have_text("Email can't be blank")
  end
  it "informs user of an invalid password" do
    fill_form email: "test@test.com", password: ""

    expect(page).to have_text("Password can't be blank")
  end
  it "informs user of an invalid credit card" do
    fill_form email: "test@test.com", 
              password: "valid-password",
              card: "bogus"

    expect(page).to have_text("Card is invalid")
  end
end
```

Comment: After researching for a while, this is the cleanest and most conventional method of approaching this problem. Strictly speaking, each test should only expect/assert 1 thing in order to truly be a unit test. That keeps each individual test smaller and easier to maintain. Does lead to a little longer time to run the test suite, but that's the tradeoff. I've only run into 1 situation where I decided to put multiple `expect(...)` in a single test and that's because I was calling an external API and it was VERY expensive time-wise to make multiple calls.

Answer (score 1):

When writing integration tests, it's important to avoid [coupling the test to the UI](https://jakewharton.com/testing-robots/).

Here's an example:

```rb
RSpec.feature 'Signup', test_helpers: [:sign_ups] do
  before { visit signups_path }

  it 'informs user of an invalid email' do
    sign_ups.sign_up_with(email: '')
    sign_ups.should.have_error("Email can't be blank")
  end

  it 'informs user of an invalid password' do
    sign_ups.sign_up_with(email: 'test@test.com')
    sign_ups.should.have_error("Password can't be blank")
  end

  it 'informs user of an invalid credit card' do
    sign_ups.sign_up_with(email: 'test@test.com', password: 'valid-password', card: 'bogus')
    sign_ups.should.have_error('Card is invalid')
  end
end
```

which you could implement using [page objects](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html), or a library like [**Capybara Test Helpers**](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/):

```rb
class SignUpsTestHelper < Capybara::TestHelper
  def sign_up_with(email:, password: nil, card: nil)
    fill_in 'Email', with: email
    fill_in 'Password', with: password if password
    fill_in 'Card', with: card if card
    click_button 'Signup'
  end

  def have_error(message)
    have_selector('#error_explanation', text: message)
  end
end
```

That said, sometimes full isolation is not needed, and combining the scenarios should make the test suite significantly faster:

```rb
RSpec.feature 'Signup', test_helpers: [:sign_ups] do
  before { visit signups_path }

  it 'informs user of invalid info' do
    sign_ups.sign_up_with(email: '')
    sign_ups.should.have_error("Email can't be blank")

    sign_ups.sign_up_with(email: 'test@test.com')
    sign_ups.should.have_error("Password can't be blank")

    sign_ups.sign_up_with(email: 'test@test.com', password: 'valid-password', card: 'bogus')
    sign_ups.should.have_error('Card is invalid')
  end
end
```

Notice that now that the test code is well encapsulated, it's still easy to follow in the condensed version.